# javascript checkbox to button

Tags: javascript, forms

```
    <li class="last filter">
    <?php echo $bps_options['message']; ?>&nbsp;
        <input id="bps_Show" type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:bps_toggleForm()" />
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

--

A form is shown when a check box is checked. How do I change this to a normal button?
Thanks

Comment: Just javascript or are you capable of using Jquery too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to wrap your checkbox `input` tag in span, obtain a reference to that span, and replace the `innerHTML` with a new button element with important attributes copied over.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use Jquery you can do this by swapping the innerHTML on a parent element.  It's a little harder without Jquery but still doable.

If you can use Jquery you can use .replaceWith().

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <input id="bps_Show" type="checkbox" value="click me" onclick="toggleInput();"/>
</div>
```

**Javascript Version** [JSFiddle with just javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/kasdega/Yu8RW/2/)

```
var oldInput = "<input id=\"bps_Show\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\click me\" onclick=\"toggleInput();\"/>";
var newInput = "<input id=\"bps_Show\" type=\"button\" value=\click me\" onclick=\"toggleInput();\"/>";

function toggleInput() {
    var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
    var elm = document.getElementById('bps_Show');
    //bps_toggleForm();

    if(elm.getAttribute("type") == "button") {
        wrapper.innerHTML = oldInput;
    } else {
        wrapper.innerHTML = newInput;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**JQuery:**  [Jquery Version](http://jsfiddle.net/kasdega/Yu8RW/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var newInput = "<input id=\"bps_Show\" type=\"button\" value=\"Click Me\"/>";
    var oldInput;

    $("#bps_Show").live("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //bps_toggleForm();
        oldInput = $(this);
        $(this).replaceWith(newInput);
        newInput = oldInput;
    });
});
```